# How do I run in parallel batches from a skip take of a list?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a list of orders in which I am trying to process 2000 at a time.  What I want to do is process each of the 2000 order batches at the same time and once all are finished return.  In the below sample code I am taking a list of orders and sending the batch to CreateOrders when complete adding it to the completed orders as I need them all returned back.   How can I parallel process these batches of 2000 in this case?

```
public List<Order> BatchOrders(List<Order> orders)
        {
            var completedOrders = new List<Order>();
            int batchSize = 2000;

            //Create orders in batch
            for (int i = 0; i < orders.Count(); i += batchSize )
            {
                var batchOrders = orders.Skip(i).Take(batchSize).ToList();
                completedOrders.AddRange(CreateOrders(batchOrders));
            }

            return completedOrders;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to choose the number you process at a time? Why not leave to to the runtime system, which knows what resources are available?

Comment: @JasperKent, that's a good question! It _could_ be due to a downstream system that has limited throughput, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: They are getting passed to this external api and the issue is that system after a certain amount does not run well so we have the ability to set a number to send in the batch at a time.

Comment: "What I want to do is process each of the 2000 order batches at the same time" and "system after a certain amount does not run well" are contradictory. In that case, you will be sending maybe tens of thousands of orders concurrently. What will the backend do then?

Comment: Or is that 2.000 run sequentially? :)

Comment: @OguzOzgul the external system can handle multiple batches but each batch after a certain size has issues :).

Comment: Now that's someone else's problem I guess :) Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a helper method like this:

```
public static class BatchExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> col, int batchSize = 2000)
    {
        var batch = new List<T>(batchSize);
        foreach (var o in col)
        {
            batch.Add(o);
            if (batch.Count == batchSize)
            {
                var rc = batch;
                batch = new List<T>(batchSize);
                yield return rc;
            }
        }
        if (batch.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return batch;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to handle each batch in parallel, something like:

```
public List<Order> BatchOrders(List<Order> orders)
{
    var completedOrderBatches = new ConcurrentBag<List<Order>>();

    var opts = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };

    Parallel.ForEach(orders.Batch(),opts,  
        batch =>
           {
               completedOrderBatches.Add(CreateOrders(batch));
           });

    return completedOrderBatches.SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
}
```

If you need the batch number in CreateOrders, then you can use Parallel.For instead of Paralle.ForEach.  Just like using `for` instead of `foreach`.

```
public List<Order> BatchOrders(List<Order> orders)
{
    var completedOrders = new ConcurrentBag<List<Order>>();

    var opts = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };

    int batchSize = 2000;
    var batches = orders.Batch(batchSize).ToList();
    Parallel.For(0,batches.Count,opts, 
        batchNum =>
           {
               var batch = batches[batchNum];
               var startId = batchNum * batchSize;
               completedOrders.Add(CreateOrders(batch, startId));
           });

    return completedOrders.SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
}
```

Comment: great tx I will check this out appreciate it

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread safe. You should not use `AddRange` in this way.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov good catch.  Updated answer with thread-safe accumulator.

Comment: awesome thanks so much @DavidBrowne this is great appreciate all the feedback and help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public List<Order> BatchOrders(List<Order> orders)
{        
    int batchSize = 2000;

    List <Task<IEnumerable<Order>>> tasks = new List<Task<IEnumerable<Order>>>();

    //Create orders in batch
    for (int i = 0; i < orders.Count; i += batchSize)
    {
        var batchOrders = orders.Skip(i).Take(batchSize).ToList();

        // Run CreateOrders as a task and store the task
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CreateOrders(batchOrders)));
    }

    var allTasks = tasks.ToArray();

    // Wait till all the tasks are complete
    Task.WaitAll(allTasks);

    var completedOrders = new List<Order>();

    //Merge the results
    foreach (var task in allTasks)
        completedOrders.AddRange(task.Result);

    return completedOrders;
}
```

Comment: thanks Jasper that is also a good option using Task in that case.  Thanks all this is a huge help

Comment: One minor improvement, a corner case, really - there is no guarantee that you can always `Take(batchSize)`, say there are 2001 elements and batch size is 2000

Comment: Also, you are using .WaitAll which is a blocking operation

Comment: `WaitAll` implements the `once all are finished return` requirement.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but we could use `Task.WhenAll` and then return a `Task` that can be `await`ed and make all code `async`

Comment: @ironstone13 What improvement are you suggesting? If there is only `1` item in the collection, `.Take(2000)` will just return that one item.

Comment: I read that as just being about balancing. If you have 2001, why not split it as 1000 and 1001?

Comment: @RufusL, yes, you are right, this is exactly what happens, my mistake. Confirmed this with docs and source code. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for this input you guys all rock I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it with the help of the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. You would need two blocks, one [`BatchBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1) to do the batching and one [`TransformManyBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformmanyblock-2) to process each batch.

```
List<Order> BatchOrders(List<Order> orders,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<Order>(batchSize: 2000);

    var tranformBlock = new TransformManyBlock<Order[], Order>(batch =>
    {
        return CreateOrders(batch.ToList());
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
        CancellationToken = cancellationToken
    });

    batchBlock.LinkTo(tranformBlock,
        new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

    foreach (var order in orders)
    {
        batchBlock.Post(order);
    }
    batchBlock.Complete();

    var results = new List<Order>();
    while (tranformBlock.OutputAvailableAsync().Result)
    {
        while (tranformBlock.TryReceive(out var order))
        {
            results.Add(order);
        }
    }
    tranformBlock.Completion.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return results;
}
```

This library is embedded on .NET Core. The advantages are:

1. Built-in support for configuring the maximum degree of parallelism
2. Built-in support for cancellation
3. Fails fast in case of an exception (contrary to `Task.WaitAll` for example)
4. Can handle more complex scenarios
5. Can be converted relatively easily to async

And the disadvantages:

1. Less familiar than the alternatives
2. Retrieving the results from the final block is somewhat cumbersome
3. Not embedded on .NET Framework (needs a [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) installation)

Answer (score -1):

I think the answers that are already provided are great!

I would like to share mine, since I love declarative and concise code.

Please note that while this code has **better readability**, it has **worse runtime efficiency**, since source collection is enumerated as many times as there are batches.

Extension methods are defined on `IReadonlyCollection<T>` and not on `IEnumerable<T>` to exclude lazily evaluated enumerations, that load the data from external data souces.

First, some extension helpers

```
public static class BatchExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakePart<T>(this IReadOnlyCollection<T> data, int batchNumber, int batchSize) =>
        data
        .Skip(batchNumber * batchSize)
        .Take(batchSize);

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IReadOnlyCollection<T> data, int batchSize) =>
        Enumerable
        .Range(0, data.Count / batchSize)
        .Select(index => TakePart(data, index, batchSize));
}
```

Now, your method is rather short and concise

```
    async Task<IEnumerable<CreatedOrder>> BatchOrders(List<Order> orders, int batchSize)
    {
        var batches = 
            orders
            .Batch(batchSize)
            .Select(batch => Task.Run(() => CreateOrders(batch)))
            .ToArray();

        var result = (await Task.WhenAll(batches)).SelectMany(x=>x);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: FYI, You should be able to just `.Take(batchSize)`

Comment: Yes, @RufusL, thank you, you are right. Great to get to know something i did not know before. I have updated my post. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to use the ParallelFor and it seemed to work well in this case I will try this one later as well check for performance on it all.   I need to get the start position as well coming into CreateOrders such as my original post with skip and take "i" I need that as in CreateOrders I use that for creating a file name.    The answer with the ParallelFor above added that and it seems to work well.   Thanks again to all.